# Which filesystem is this?

Tags: filesystem, loop-device

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  I have a file that is a diskette image.  The diskette was written by an electronic music device, an Ensoniq ASR-10 sampler as it happens. (I don't know much about electronic music.)  The question is: what kind of file system is on that diskette?  I've run **strings** on the image and verified that the files, whose names I know, are almost certainly there.  I need to extract them from the image. I guessed that the filesystem was **msdos**, but my attempt to mount them via a loop device failed.  (In case it's relevant, the **mount** command I tried was

**mount -t msdos /dev/loop0 /mnt/floppy/**

How can I extract the files from the image?

What I really trying to do is to create another diskette with a different set of files. I figured that if I can determine the filesystem, I can probably build a new image, based on that filesystem, and populate it with the desired files.

Comment: *"I've run strings on the image and verified that the files, whose names I know, are almost certainly there"* - you should elaborate and add detail since this would seem to be helpful information

Comment: this diskettes are special formated.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensoniq_ASR-10

Answer (score 0):

Try e.g.

```
mount -t msdos -o loop,ro diskette.img /mnt
```

where diskette.img is your diskette image. The mount command takes care of the loop device automatically.

Comment: -t msdos doesn't work.  Apparently the filesystem is  something peculiar to Ensoniq.